# Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.onProgressUpdate

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

[image]Starting from Android 4.0 I have the problem ( on 2.3.6 it is working).

`onProgressUpdate` it should be already in UI thread.
I have tried `activity.runOnUiThread` now is with a `Handler` version, ofc first was without any of tham. How to fix it?

```
public class ReadDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONArray> {

    private Activity activity;
    protected ProgressDialog dlg;

    private long startRead, endRead, endJson;

    public ReadDataTask(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        dlg = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dlg.show();
        startRead = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        if (values != null && values.length > 0) {
            final String msg = values[0];
            new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    dlg.setMessage(msg);// android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
                }
            });
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... params) {
           ... long task here
           publishProgress("Converting to JSON: " + (1 + i) + " / " + dataList.size());
```

Comment: Please post your stack trace.

Comment: @CommonsWare updated with a screenshot, also it is marked the code line in source, where is happening. Moved the 
  dlg = new ProgressDialog(activity); to onPreExecute() and still have the error

Comment: Remove the `Handler` stuff and try again with `dlg.setMessage()` called directly in `onProgressUpdate()`. If you get the same exception, post the *complete* stack trace. You can do this by highlighting the lines, copying them to the clipboard (e.g., Ctrl-C), and pasting them here formatted as source. On an unrelated note, delete your `activity` data member, as the only place where you might be using it outside of the constructor is `doInBackground()`, which is one place where you should *not* be referencing the activity, due to configuration changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create handler only once in `onPreExecute()` which is called from UI thread and save a reference to it, than post to it in `onProgressUpdate()`.

Handler posts to thread that it has been created on.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all!
The implementation of solution:

```
private Activity activity;
protected ProgressDialog dlg;
private Handler myHandler;

private long startRead, endRead, endJson;

public ReadDataTask(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    myHandler = new Handler();

    dlg = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    dlg.show();
    startRead = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    if (values != null && values.length > 0) {
        final String msg = values[0];
        myHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                dlg.setMessage(msg);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me.

```
myHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                dlg.setMessage(msg);
            }
        });
```